# can i set uitableviewcell font to custom

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to set 'cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Xiomara" size:15];' but nothing happens. I've already added this font to the project and everyware except cell, I can use it.

Also I use SWRevealViewController and this table view is a slide menu.

Comment: have you added a new key in the array named "Fonts Provided by application" in the plist file?

Comment: try this [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Xiomara" size:15]];

Comment: yes, otherwise how can I use it in labels

Comment: @MohitPopat this code is also doesn't work

Comment: Did you check font name `Xiomara` is also like this in font book?. because if it is different in font book then it will not work

Comment: @MohitPopat I use it as Xiomara for labels and also if I create a custom cell it will work, but I need to implement it this way

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is correct. Maybe you can increase the size to like 22 to see the visible change. Because the same thing is working fine for me.

Comment: I can't do anything with cell content, it take all settings from storyboard.

Comment: No... Do this cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Xiomara" size:22]; instead of cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Xiomara" size:15];

Comment: But its working fine for me. Maybe u r missing something else.